# What is the maximum accepted version of Xcode for uploads?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently updated to the release version of Xcode 13 on my Mac. Now when I upload an iOS App build to Apple using the upload endpoint (via fastlane) I get an error saying "Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported SDK or version of Xcode. If you plan to submit this build to the App Store, make sure you are using the versions listed in https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf16aefe3b or later."

```
% xcodebuild -version

Xcode 13.0

Build version 13A233
```

I also deleted the old beta Xcode and restarted my mac to be sure. Anyone else having this issue? Any recommendations?

Thanks!

Update: this eventually went away. And did so in a way that, suggested it was possibly something being stuck on Apple's side. After updating fastlane and deleting everything Xcode related and trying again it didn't work. However after doing an upload from Xcode after the above, it failed one last time with the same stated reason, BUT THEN it began working from there forward from all upload sources.

I also "developer rejected" a "pending release" that was built from before I was having this issue. Unclear if that was related.

Comment: Where is the error message coming from?  If it is coming from FastLane then it sounds like it needs an update (or you need to install an update) so that it is aware of Xcode 13 which is definitely supported for App Store uploads.

Comment: My understanding is comment is coming from Fastlane's reporting of what Apple's servers reported back.  "[Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90534:"   I will try updating fast lane.

Comment: Please don't add the solution / outcome as part of the question. Stack Overflow is question and answer. If you have a solution or other good outcome, give it as an answer.